# TypeScript module '*' force compiler error

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to tell the TypeScript compiler to raise an error when importing from a non-existant file? I have this line:

```
import { SignInModal } from '../modals/sign-in/sign-in';
```

`sign-in.ts` was renamed to something else and no longer exists. TypeScript compiled my project just fine, but it failed at runtime. In Visual Studio Code, I hover over `'../modals/sign-in/sign-in'` and it says `module '*'`.

Just to make sure it wasn't some type of caching in the editor or the typescript compiler, I wrote a new import that pointed to something that definitely doesn't exist and never did exist. Same thing. 
Here's a screen cap of how it looks in vscode. 
[image]

Is there a way to tell the typescript compiler NOT to import from `'*'` by default so that I can catch those stale imports at compile-time?

Comment: It should do that already, Are you 100% sure that nothing exists at that path?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. I updated my question to show an example of importing something that 100% doesn't exist, and it's the same thing

Comment: As Chris said, the compiler should already throw an error. Can you post your tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was not TypeScript's doing. It was because of a file that the Ionic framework includes in their project templates. They include a `declarations.d.ts` file that was including the `'*'`:

```ts
/*
  Declaration files are how the Typescript compiler knows about the type information(or shape) of an object.
  They're what make intellisense work and make Typescript know all about your code.

  A wildcard module is declared below to allow third party libraries to be used in an app even if they don't
  provide their own type declarations.

  To learn more about using third party libraries in an Ionic app, check out the docs here:
  http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/

  For more info on type definition files, check out the Typescript docs here:
  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html
*/
declare module '*';
```

Comment: Just want to say that this is terrible on the part of the Ionic team for adding this by default.

Comment: FYI, Starting with Ionic 3.3.0, they have removed this file. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v3.3.0

"Another optional step is to remove the src/declarations.d.ts file. This is a legacy file introduced early with ionic-angular projects to improve compatibility between TypeScript and third-party libraries. Due to improvements in TypeScript, this file is no longer necessary. By removing this file, the TypeScript compiler will be able to provide more accurate error messages for import statements."